# Hibernate persist without transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was following a tutorial on Hibernate and saw the following code:

```
package com.websystique.spring.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class AbstractDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void persist(Object entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(Object entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if `persist()` (or `save()` or `delete()`) can be used without a transaction? As it seems to be the case here.

Comment: I will note in passing that this is very poor code for a wide variety of reasons. Ideally, use Spring Data JPA (and use constructor injection).

Comment: You can't persist with out a transaction. Please look up to your hibernate conf file. It should have provide the transaction through interceptors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cant save or persist object without transaction you have to commit the transaction after saving the object otherwise it won't save in database.
***Without transaction you can only retrieve object from database***

Answer (score 2):

Actually, **IT IS POSSIBLE** to persist without a transaction with Hibernate but it's **STRONGLY DISCOURAGED** because of performance and data consistency issues.

#### `application.properties`:

```
hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true
```

#### Spring `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true
```

<sub>As I had to use this setting for a very specific reason. I think it might be of use to some people, even though it's not recommended to be used in production code.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As said you CAN'T save anything in the database without a active transaction.
It seens that you are using a container, in this case Spring. 
Spring can control transactions by interceptos like JavaEE.
You can read more here: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.4.0.Final/en-US/html/interceptors.html

Also this looks like a really poor example to demonstrate:

```
public class TransactionalInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private Session session;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Object result = null;
        boolean openTransaction = !session.getTransaction().isActive();
        if(openTransaction)
            session.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            result = ctx.proceed();
            if(openTransaction)
                session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new TransactionException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```